# How can I access a specific object in my array using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have created a dynamic array of objects which is created through inquirer.
But I cannot figure out how to access a specific object in the array
EDIT: this is how the console has logged my array

So for example, how can I access the 2nd Engineer (Mark)?

Keep in mind the array will change depending on the user input

```
team = [
  Manager {
    name: 'Nicole',
    id: '1',
    email: 'nicole@gmail.com',
    officeNumber: '5'
  },
  Engineer {
    name: 'Zoe',
    id: '2',
    email: 'zoe@gmail.com',
    github: 'zozo'
  },
  Engineer {
    name: 'Mark',
    id: '3',
    email: 'mark@gmail.com',
    github: 'emman'
  },
  Engineer {
    name: 'Joe',
    id: '4',
    email: 'joe@gmail.com',
    github: 'joey'
  }
  Intern {
    name: 'Seb',
    id: '5',
    email: 'seb@gmail.com',
    school: 'UWA'
  }
]
```

Comment: Ehm, that's not actually valid code? Did you run this? Aside from that, you could use a `for` loop to check each object in the `team` array and look for the object where `name === "Mark"`. That way it will keep working if more objects are added.

Comment: It’s not _wrong_, it’s just not an object literal. This is very likely how a console will log it. So what are `Manager`, `Engineer`, and `Intern`? Classes? Then do `team.filter((obj) => obj instanceof Engineer)[1]`.

Comment: Sorry yes that is how the console has logged it. Apologies I am very new to coding! Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `find` method. If there is no such Mark then `find` return null.

If you want find Engineer Mark

```js
const result = data.find(x => {
  return x instanceof Engineer && x.name === 'Mark'  
})
```

[Update]
If you want find the **second** Engineer

```js
const result = data.filter(x => {
  return x instanceof Engineer
})[1]
```

Comment: _“how can I access the 2nd Engineer (Mark)?”_ reads like _“How to find the second item which is an `Engineer`, which happens to have a `name` of `"Mark"` in this example”_, not like _“How to find the first item which is both an `Engineer` and has a `name` of `"Mark"`”_.

Comment: @SebastianSimon thanks, I have updated answer. Question is not clear enough.

Comment: This is perfect thankyou! Still learning so unsure of how to write things correctly yet. Appreciate the options

Answer (score 0):

As [Sepehr jozef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15143982/sepehr-jozef) mentioned the strucure is not that handy. If we take his structure you can find it via the [.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) Method.

```
var team = [
{
    name: 'Nicole',
    id: '1',
    email: 'nicole@gmail.com',
    officeNumber: '5',
},
{
    name: 'Zoe',
    id: '2',
    email: 'zoe@gmail.com',
    github: 'zozo'
},
{
    name: 'Mark',
    id: '3',
    email: 'mark@gmail.com',
    github: 'emman'
},
{
    name: 'Joe',
    id: '4',
    email: 'joe@gmail.com',
    github: 'joey'
},
{
    name: 'Seb',
    id: '5',
    email: 'seb@gmail.com',
    school: 'UWA'
 }
]

const mark = team.find(function(teamMember){
    return teamMember.name === "Mark";
})
```

The variable "mark" contains now the object of the engineer "Mark".

Answer (score -1):

first of all, your structure is wrong.

it should be:

```
var team = [
    {
        name: 'Nicole',
        id: '1',
        email: 'nicole@gmail.com',
        officeNumber: '5',
    },
    {
        name: 'Zoe',
        id: '2',
        email: 'zoe@gmail.com',
        github: 'zozo'
    },
    {
        name: 'Mark',
        id: '3',
        email: 'mark@gmail.com',
        github: 'emman'
    },
    {
        name: 'Joe',
        id: '4',
        email: 'joe@gmail.com',
        github: 'joey'
    },
    {
        name: 'Seb',
        id: '5',
        email: 'seb@gmail.com',
        school: 'UWA'
    }
]
```

and to get mark(2) you should use:

```
team[3].name
```

Comment: He provide `console.log` output which print class name of objects.